# Using a WebView widget to authorize access

Tags: android, .htaccess, webview

I am trying to access a server that requires authorization using the WebView widget in Android. I think it's the .htaccess type of authorization.

I works with the default browser provided with the OS, but when I try it with a WebView.. it gives a `401` immediately.

Any ideas on how I can have a WebView present the dialog to enter the user/pass (and remember it)?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using a `WebViewClient`, overriding its [`onReceivedHttpAuthRequest()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html#onReceivedHttpAuthRequest%28android.webkit.WebView,%20android.webkit.HttpAuthHandler,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) method.